# How can i get the java class from Hibernate ClassMetaData

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using the following code to get all ClassMetaData from the sessionFactory.

```
...
Map allClassMetadata = getSessionFactory().getAllClassMetadata();
Set<String> entityNames = allClassMetadata.keySet();
for(String entityName : entityNames) {
    ClassMetadata classMetaData = (ClassMetadata)allClassMetadata.get(entityName);
    Class entityClass = 

}
...
```

Is it possible to retrieve the according java class. I've seen the method `getMappedClass(EntityMode mode)`. But what does entitymode mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, put `getEntityMode( EntityMode.POJO )`.  There are a few Entity modes that can be used to mapping to things other than POJOs such as XML or Maps.

Answer (score 1):

**As of 2016 (Hibernate 5.2), `getAllClassMetadata` is deprecated.**

I guess this could be used instead:

```
Set<EntityType<?>> entities = sessionFactory.getMetamodel().getEntities();

List<?> classes = entities.stream()
                          .map(EntityType::getJavaType)
                          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```